# Does $k(f,g)=k(h)$, where $f$ and $g$ are odd polynomials, imply that $h$ is also an odd polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero (I do not mind to assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$, if this helps).

[Lüroth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem) says that a field $L$, $k \subset L \subset k(t)$ containing a nonconstant polynomial over $k$ is equal to $k(h)$ for some $h \in k[t]$.
More precisely, by Lüroth theorem there exists such $h \in k(t)$, and E. Noether has proved that actually one can take $h \in k[t]$ (see "Selected Topics on Polynomials" by A. Schinzel).

Let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]-k$, and $L:=k(f,g)$.
By Lüroth-Noether theorem we have $k(f,g)=k(h)$, for some $h=h(t) \in k[t]$. 
Further assume that $f$ and $g$ are odd polynomials, namely,
$f=a_{2n+1}t^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}t^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_3t^3+a_1t$ and $g=b_{2m+1}t^{2m+1}+b_{2m-1}t^{2m-1}+\cdots+b_3t^3+b_1t$,
$a_i,b_j \in k$.

> Is it true that $h$ must be an odd polynomial too?
>   If this is too much to ask, than at least is it true that $h$ must have an odd degree? (though it can have monomials of even degrees).

**For example:** $f=t^3, g=t^7$. Then $\frac{g}{f^2}=\frac{t^7}{t^6}=t$, and then $L=k(t)$, so $h=t$ is also an odd polynomial. Of course, this is just a simple example which may not hint about a general solution.

**Another example:** $f=t^3, g=t^7+t^5$. Then $\frac{g}{f}=\frac{t^7+t^5}{t^3}=
\frac{t^3(t^4+t^2)}{t^3}=t^4+t^2$. (Notice that $\frac{g}{f^2}=\frac{t^7+t^5}{t^6}=t+\frac{1}{t}$, but I do not know if this helps). What is $h$?

**A trivial remark:** Since $k(h)=k(h+\lambda)$ for any $\lambda \in k$, it is no loss of generality to assume that $h(0)=0$ , so we avoid trivial counterexamples for which $h(0)\neq 0$ (such $h$ is not an odd polynomial).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Are you assuming $kf[f,g]\subset k[h]$? If so, since $f(t)=P(h(t))$ for some polynomial $P(x)$, we have $\deg_t f=\deg_x P\cdot \deg_t h$ and thus $h$ must have odd degree.

Comment: Thank you. I am not assuming that $k[f,g] \subset k[h]$, though this is a nice special case (which I thought about when reading https://lup.lub.lu.se/search/publication/c263497a-3765-41f0-a16c-896bbcadd241 about SAGBI bases). We just know that, by Luroth-Noether theorem $k(f,g)=k(h)$ for some $h(t) \in k[t]$, so $f(t)=\frac{A(h)}{B(h)}$ and $g(t)=\frac{C(h)}{D(h)}$ for some polynomials $A(x),B(x),C(x),D(x) \in k[x]$. The difficult step (if possible) is to show that $B(x) \in k$ and $D(x) \in k$.

Comment: From $f=\frac{A(h)}{B(h)}$ we obtain $\deg_t(f)+\deg_x(B)\deg_t(h)=\deg_x(A)\deg_t(h)$, so $\deg_t(f)=\deg_x(A)\deg_t(h)-\deg_x(B)\deg_t(h)$, namely, $\deg_t(f)=(\deg_x(A)-\deg_x(B))\deg_t(h)$, which shows that $\deg_t(h)$ is even.

Comment: I meant: "which shows that $\deg_t(h)$ is odd", of course.